# Laravel 5.4 and Socialite redirect to calling page after Twitter login

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, twitter, laravel-socialite

I'm putting together a site that has a Twitter login through Socialite in Laravel 5.4. Right now once the user is logged in, I redirect to the home page; however, I'd like to be able to redirect the user to whichever page he was on activating the "Sign In with Twitter" link. I tried using `return redirect()->back()`, but since the last request was to Twitter's api, that just causes an infinite loop. I'm sure this must be pretty basic, but I can't seem to figure it out. This is the controller handling my auth requests:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectPath = '/home';

    /**
     * Redirect user to OAuth Provider.
     *
     * @param $provider
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from provider. check if user already
     * exists in our db by looking up their provider_id in the db.
     * If user exists, log them in. Otherwise, create a new user then log them in.
     * After login, redirect them to the authenticated users homepage.
     *
     * @param $provider
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return redirect("auth/$provider");
        }
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);

        return redirect($this->redirectPath);
    }

    /**
     * If a user has registered before using social auth, return the user
     * else, create a new user object.
     *
     * @param $user Socialite user object
     * @param $provider Social auth provider
     * @return User
     */
    public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
        if ($authUser) {
            return $authUser;
        }

        return User::create([
            'name'        => $user->name,
            'handle'      => $user->nickname,
            'provider'    => $provider,
            'provider_id' => $user->id,
            'avatar'      => $user->avatar_original,
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use `intended` function

Answer (score 3):

What you want is default `Laravel` authentication behavior.

```
return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
    ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
```

If a user visits `/privatepage` and that page is protected by the `auth middleware` then the user is redirected to the login page and `/privatepage` is saved to session as `url.intended`. Then after a successful authentication `Laravel` checks if the session has the `url.intended` key, and if does, it will redirect to the URL saved in the session. If not, it will redirect to whatever page you have defined, default is `/home`.

If you would like to manually handle what happens when a user is authenticated, then you can create a function called `authenticated()` which will be called instead with manual redirects.

**OR**

If you have common page for `guest` visitors and `logged in` users you can store `URL` into `Session` something like this:

```
Session::flash('url',Request::server('HTTP_REFERER'));
```

and use this after manipulation or authentication as:

```
return redirect(Session::get('url'));
```

Hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to the `Session::flash('url', Request::server('HTTP_REFERER'));` solution. I attached the current path as a parameter to the end of the href like so in my link: `href="{{ url('/auth/facebook') }}?last-url={!! htmlentities(request()->path()) !!}"` Then I added this to my `redirectToProvider()` function: `request()->session()->put('last_url', request()->query('last-url'));`

I prefer your answer though, as it involves less code, and adding the parameter is redundant since the data is already being sent in the request through the `$__SERVER` variable

Answer (score 0):

return redirect()->intended('/home#');